# How to prevent a Vim Ex command from taking too much time?

Tags: vim

I have a Vim mapping which overrides the default `n` command, to move the cursor on the next match, but also to display the number of matches of the search register, as well as the index of the match under the cursor.

It works, except that when the pattern becomes a little complex and/or there are many matches, the script can take a lot of time (several seconds). The results are cached, so after the initial `n`, as long as the buffer isn't changed, the consecutive `n` don't cause any slowdown.

After profiling the script, I've found that the command which, by far, took the most time was:

```
let output = execute(a:range.'s///gen')
```

I use it in a [function](https://github.com/lacygoill/vim-search/blob/da132a5a8de9b1ffc44fb22d6cfd48f5987dbb7b/autoload/search.vim#L403-L406), to compute the number of matches inside an arbitrary range:

```
fu! s:matches_in_range(range) abort
    let output = execute(a:range.'s///gen')
    return str2nr(matchstr(output, '\d\+'))
endfu
```

To solve this issue, I had 2 ideas, but they both have a problem.

I could try and guess whether the command is going to take too much time, by computing the number of matches on a small sub-range of the initial range, before computing in the rest of the lines.

But most of the matches could be outside this sub-range, so the test could fail to detect that it will take too much time overall.

Or, I could refactor the function, using a `while` loop and the `search()` function. After each iteration, I could test how much time has elapsed since the beginning, and cancel when it goes beyond a certain limit. Another benefit would be the 4th optional argument `{timeout}` which can be passed to `search()`. If the pattern is really too complex, and even the 1st iteration of the loop takes too much time, this argument could stop the function. Here's what it could look like (without the timeout argument):

```
fu! Total_matches() abort
    let view      = winsaveview()
    let total     = 0
    let matchline = search(@/, 'cW')
    let time      = reltime()

    call cursor(1, 1)
    while matchline && total <= 9999
        if reltimefloat(reltime(time)) > 1
            echo 'too many matches'
            call winrestview(view)
            return
        endif
        let total += 1
        let matchline = search(@/, 'W')
    endwhile

    call winrestview(view)
    echo @/.' ['.total.']'
endfu

nno cd :call Total_matches()<cr>
```

But, in my limited testing (I only searched for simple patterns like `the` or `foobar` in a single file with a few thousand lines), it seems that the `while` loop is generally slower than `s///gen`. Sometimes just a little bit, sometimes much more (by a factor of 8 for example).

How can I prevent a Vim Ex command from taking too much time, in the general case, or at least in this specific one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already outlined the obvious approaches:

- A few low-level functions like `search()` take a `{timeout}` value, to avoid them blocking user action for too long. Unfortunately, it's not a 100% equivalent of `:%s///gn`, so you need additional code (here: a slower loop in Vimscript).
- You could implement heuristics to estimate whether the invocation will be slow, and then don't do it. This will never be perfect, a lot of effort, but maybe good enough.

#### Recommendation

How important is this additional (search summary) information for the user? Usually, probably not essential, but there may be cases where the user would be willing to wait some more seconds for this.

I would ensure that the primary function (here: the `n` command that jumps to the next match) will always executed (first), and that the summary generation can be aborted by pressing `<C-C>` (perhaps multiple times, to break out of `:%s` and then out of your function). Basically, this means `:catch`ing `Vim:Interrupt`, see `:help catch-interrupt`.

#### My approach

I have written the [SearchPosition plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2634) to show such summary information *on demand*. It does not integrate with `n` and always must be triggered separately. (The default mapping is `<A-n>`, so that it can be quickly triggered in conjunction with an `n` command.) This adds one additional mapping, and puts the onus on the user, but at least for me, I seldomly need the summary, and not always together with jumping to matches.